# Convert interface{} parameter into *http.Request or *http.Response in Go

Tags: http, go, request, response

I'm tying to create an util function that will read body of the Request/Response and return it.
Here's what I've done for the moment:

```
func GetBody(in interface{}) []byte {
    var body io.Reader
    var statusCode int

    switch v := in.(type) {
        case *http.Request, *http.Response:
            body = v.Body
            statusCode = v.StatusCode
        default:
            log.Fatal("Only http.Request and http.Response parameters can be accepted to parse body")
    }

    if statusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalf("Received status code [%d] instead of [200]", statusCode)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return body
}
```

But I'm receiving an error of compiler: `v.Body undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`
Am I missing something or it's impossible to make a generic function that will server both for `*http.Request` and `*http.Response`

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the double `case`.

`v` is still an `interface{}` because it could be either an `*http.Request` or an `*http.Response`

```
switch v := in.(type) {
    case *http.Request
        body = v.Body
        statusCode = v.StatusCode
    case *http.Response:
        body = v.Body
        statusCode = v.StatusCode
    default:
        log.Fatal("Only http.Request and http.Response parameters can be accepted to parse body")
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers which directly address the issue with your type switch, I'd like to point out an alternative solution.
Note, the `interface{}` solution is perfectly fine and may easily be considered preferable to this. This is presented for edification.

First, as a slight aside, if the thing you were interested in was a common method (e.g. `Write` or `Cookies`) rather than a common field (`Body`), it would be easy and better to access it via a custom interface.

Either by defining a type:

```
type cookier interface { // Should probably use a better name
    Cookies() []*http.Cookie
}  
func ShowCookies1(r cookier) {
    log.Println("Got cookies:", r.Cookies())
}
```

Or by using an anonymous type in the function definition:

```
func ShowCookies2(r interface {
    Cookies() []*http.Cookie
}) {
    log.Println("Got cookies:", r.Cookies())
}
```

These functions can accept anything that has a `Cookies` method, this includes `*http.Request` and `*http.Response`.

Unfortunately, in your particular case you wish to access a common field rather than a common method so you can't directly just use a matching interface.

You could make a small wrapper type that adds a `GetBody` method (one could argue such a function should have been defined in the standard package).

```
type reqbody struct{ *http.Request }
type respbody struct{ *http.Response }
type getbody interface {
    GetBody() io.ReadCloser
}

func (r reqbody) GetBody() io.ReadCloser  { return r.Body }
func (r respbody) GetBody() io.ReadCloser { return r.Body }

func GetBody2(r getbody) ([]byte, error) {
    body := r.GetBody()
    defer body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(body)
}
```

The caller knows what type they have and does one of:

```
    buf, err = GetBody2(reqbody{req})
    buf, err = GetBody2(respbody{resp})
```

In some sense this is uglier than just using `interface{}`.
But it has the benefit that instead of having a function that takes absolutely any type and panics/errors **at run-time** if a programmer mistakenly calls it with something not of the appropriate type,
this instead forces the caller to safely pass something you known is of the correct type **at compile time**.

Looking at this further, you're just reading everything from an `io.ReadCloser` and then closing it so it could further be simplified to the following
(which probably *is* better than your `interface{}` solution):

```
func GetReqBody(r *http.Request) io.ReadCloser   { return r.Body }
// Could add checking r.StatusCode to the following one as well:
func GetRespBody(r *http.Response) io.ReadCloser { return r.Body }
func ReadAndClose(rc io.ReadCloser) ([]byte, error) {
    defer rc.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(rc)
}
```

Again, the caller knows what type they have and does one of:

```
    buf, err = ReadAndClose(GetReqBody(req))
    buf, err = ReadAndClose(GetRespBody(resp))
```

Or just:

```
    buf, err = ReadAndClose(req.Body)
    buf, err = ReadAndClose(resp.Body)
```

You can see an example of all these options on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IvYcBzyxBW).

Finally, be careful using `ioutil.ReadAll`.
Often it is better to avoid pre-reading an entire file or network steam into a buffer and instead process it as a stream as it is being read.
In particular, it's trivial to make an HTTP request with an arbitrary large body as a denial of service attack or to waste server resources
([`http.MaxBytesReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader) can also help).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is more something like that:

```
switch in.(type) {
    case *http.Request:
        body = v.(*http.Request).Body
    case *http.Response:
        body = v.(*http.Response).Body
    default:
        log.Fatal(...)
}
```

EDIT: I removed the wrong part of my answer, see HectorJ's answer for the more syntaxic please way of doing this.

Comment: Great! Thank you, Elwinar. It looks correct, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Actually `switch v := in.(type)` is correct (it's in the documentation https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

Comment: My bad. Note that the root cause and the answer are still the same… but the syntaxic suger is quite useful (and more readable).